# Lightswitch can't connect to OData service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, odata, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am working with Lightswitch in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.  When attempting to connect with an OData service, the Attach Data Source Wizard states that the service does not appear to be a valid OData service, even though the service is completely accessible via other methods (i.e. connecting to an OData service via Excel PowerPivot).  I tried to connect not only to my own service, but also to the example Northwind service at http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc.  I have also tried from multiple PCs to make sure it wasn't a setup-specific issue on the PC.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it was an issue with OData v4 vs. OData v3. I just can't believe they haven't addressed this issue since OData v4 has been available for more than a year...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please can you try the following OData service example (which uses the previous version 3 of the protocol) to see if it works:

http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/

If this works fine for you, the issue is that LightSwitch doesn't yet support v4 of the OData protocol.

You can vote for Microsoft to add this feature into LightSwitch by using the following Visual Studio UserVoice suggestion link:

[LightSwitch OData v4 UserVoice suggestion](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6146832-odata-v4)